# Diminutive forms in English.

Tags: grammar, history, suffixes, word-formation

In many languages, formation of diminutives by adding suffixes is a productive part of the language. Many languages apply a grammatical diminutive to nouns, a few—including Dutch,  Italian and Russian for instance—also use it for adjectives.

In English, noun diminutives (mainly in the sense of a smaller version of something)   are generally formed by using adjectives. A common exception, among a few others, is the usage of the suffix:

> ***[-let](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-let&allowed_in_frame=0)***:
>
> - diminutive word-forming element, Middle English, from Old French *-elet*.
>
>   from which, ***[booklet (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=booklet)***

Questions:

1. Why are diminutives in English not always formed by adding a suffix, like in French for instance?
2. Why can't a suffix like *-let* be applied to everday terms like *hand* or *car*? For example, *handlet*, or *carlet*.

(This [related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/how-are-diminutives-formed-in-recent-english-words) question does not deal with my specific issue.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33806/discussion-on-question-by-josh61-book-is-to-booklet-as-hand-is-to).

Comment: I think this question is too broad [for these reasons](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7561/59258).

Comment: @curiousdannii  - in that case you should CV as too broad.

Comment: Your question is worded strangely. 'Not always'? 'Can't'? They seem respectively trivially true or trivially false. Are you asking about '-let' in particular (that seems to be its direction at one point). Or are you asking 'why' or 'does'  English have fewer diminutives formed by suffixes?

Comment: @Josh61 I don't have the rep to vote to close.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "*My guess is that's partly because English has more words from more different sources than most languages. Consequently we've already got suitable terms in many cases, and more potentially applicable suffixes to choose from, making any neologism less "obvious"*. I think you are just right, I expected some users , more competent than I am, to suggest which  these original languages possibly were (Old German, Scandinavian etc) that probably prevailed on the French influence with respect to the diminutive forms. But probably I was expecting too much.

Comment: In addition to the suffixes that MariLou A mentions in her excellent survey of options, English has the prefix _mini_- as in _minicar_. Perhaps we might flip your question around and ask, Why don't Dutch, Italian, and Russian, for instance, have both diminutive suffixes and diminutive prefixes (if, in fact, they don't)?

Comment: @SvenYargs - as far as I know the prefix *mini* is used both in French and Italian as a diminutive. I don't know about Russian and the other languages. Mini- is sometime preferred to the 'classic diminutive' in expressions like "mini appartamento" (small flat) instead of "appartamentino" which might  sound "derogatory".

Answer (score 15):

I had better start rolling the ball...

In English the adjective *[little](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little)* is often used to describe any small object or person, which means that *little* can act like a diminutive. For example, in English we'd say:

1. a little old man (whereas in Italian *un vecchio* becomes *[un vecchietto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vecchietto)*)
2. a little man (*un uomo* → *un ometto*)
3. a little boy (*ragazzo* → *ragazzino*),
4. a little lady / woman (*donna* → *[donnetta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/donnetta)*)
5. a little baby/child/toddler (*bambino* → *[bimbetto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bimbetto)*)
6. a little hand (or) a child's hand (*mano* → *manina*)
7. a little car (*macchina* → *[macchinetta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/macchinetta)*)

According to *[Diminutives in English](https://books.google.it/books/about/Diminutives_in_English.html?id=xVwgAAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)*, the terms “lady”, “woman”, “man” and “wife” normally refer to adult persons but when *little* is placed in front, the speaker may be reducing their social status to that of children, implying that their level of intelligence or importance is similar to that of children; as a result the speaker appears superior. If, however, forms such as “little man” or “little lady” are used for small boys or girls, these expressions tend to be complimentary.

In contrast, Italian commonly employs the suffixes [-etto/a](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-etto) and [ino/a](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ino#Italian), and very effectively too, I may add. If the OP were to use the suffix *-let* in any of  the above expressions e.g., *womanlet*, or *boylet*, native speakers would think it very odd-sounding.  They may not even recognize the OP's intended meaning.

***Carlet*** as a diminutive for *car*, could work, but I imagine many would dismiss it as sounding rather twee and affected. Someone else might look it up in a dictionary, Merriam &Webster for instance, and discover it means  *[a 3-square single-cut file used by combmakers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carlet)*. Frankly, I believe the need to use a diminutive suffix never arose.

In *Diminutives in English* (2003) by Klaus P. Schneider; Geoffrey Turner argues that the term *little* makes up for the lack of diminutives in the English language.

[image]

[image]

But perhaps in Old English there were suffixes that were used to this end. I don't know, unless I do some research...

... Yes, in Old English there were suffixes that were commonly used to change nouns into diminutive nouns, similar to the French *-et*, *-ette*,  and the Italian *-etto*, and *-ino*. Many of the following terms have become rare or archaic, but some still survive today

### Old and Middle English suffixes

**-en** [Used to form the diminutives of certain nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en#Etymology_5) From Middle English, from Old English *-en*, from the neuter form of *-en*

- **chicken** (diminutive of *coc*, *cocc*)
- **maiden** (a girl or an unmarried young woman)
- **kitten** (a young cat)

**-kin** [(now archaic) Forming diminutives of nouns.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-kin) Middle English -*kin*, *-kinne*, *-kunne*, from Old English *cynna*

- **boykin** (a rare word meaning ‘a little boy’)
- **catkin** (a little cat)
- **ladykin** (a little lady)
- **[manikin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manikin)** (a short person)

**-le** [A suffix forming diminutives from other nouns; compare *-ling*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-le#Suffix) From Middle English *-el*, from Old English *-el*, *-il* ‎(diminutive suffix)

- **dimple** (a small depression or indentation in a surface.)
- **dingle** (a small, narrow or enclosed, usually wooded valley.)
- **hovel** (a poor cottage; a small, mean house; a hut.)
- **nipple** (believed to be a diminutive of *nib*, *neb* ‎(“tip, point”) *nib* +‎ *-le*)
- **nozzle** (short tube, usually tapering, forming the vent of a hose or pipe.)

**-ling** [A diminutive modifier of nouns having either the physical sense of "a younger, smaller or inferior version of what is denoted by the original noun"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ling#Suffix) From Middle English *-ling*, from Old English *-ling*, from Proto-Germanic * *-lingaz*

- **darling** (dear+ling; someone who is *dear* to me)
- **daughterling** (a young or precious daughter)
- **sonling** (a young or precious son)
- **fingerling** (‘fingerling potato’=small potato)
- **pigling** ( a little or young pig, a piglet)

(Source: Wiktionary)

**-ock** [nouns from nouns, originally with a diminutive sense.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ock) From Middle English *-ock*, from Old English *-oc*, *-uc* ‎(diminutive suffix),

- **bittock** (a little bit; a small piece) Example: *Then I cut the flesh into bittocks*...
- **bullock** (an archaic term meaning a ‘young bull’)
- **hattock** (hat +‎ -ock; a Scottish archaic word for a ‘small hat’)
- **hillock** (a small hill)
- **maddock** (an obsolete word meaning an earthworm, or a maggot)
- **paddock** (diminutive of *[pad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pad#Etymology_2_2)*, an archaic word for *toad*) Example: *Paddock calls* (Macbeth 1.1.10)
- **whinnock** (the smallest pig in a litter, a runt)

> 2. Why can't a suffix like *-let* be applied to everyday terms like hand or
>      car? For example, *handlet*, or *carlet*.

The term *car* is derived from Middle English *carre* meaning a vehicle with wheels or a ‘[small] cart’. Its diminutive form, which was [***carete***](http://findwords.info/term/carete) or ***carette***, didn't make it to the 20th century and has become obsolete.

I didn't find a term that meant a ‘small hand’ or a ‘young hand’, although English does have the following terms which contain the suffixes *-ling* and *-le*:  ***[handling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handling#Etymology_1)*** and ***[handle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handle#Etymology_1)***, but their meanings are related to the *activity* that hands do; how something performs, is treated, manipulated or to the object that involves the use of hands.

We'll just have to make do with **“little hand”.**

Comment: I wasn't surprised to find dozens of instances of [little **handies**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22little+handies%22) in Google Books, showing that we *can* press an established diminutive into service in novel contexts. It's just not so common as a *productive* technique in English as in some other languages. My guess is that's partly because English has more words from more different sources than most languages. Consequently we've *already* got suitable terms in many cases, and more *potentially* applicable suffixes to choose from, making any neologism less "obvious".

Comment: Good catch, but I note that it is in the plural because the singular " handy" means something quite different

Comment: Normally, I'd say that English is extremely flexible, and lends itself to new coinages and portmanteaus, but in the department of *diminutives* it's definitely lacking. However, the expressions "a little boy", "a little toy", "little shoes" etc. are used every day, so why would English use a suffix? The adjective *little* has two syllables, *small* has one, whereas *etto* and *ino*  have two syllables, "a little toy" or "a small toy" is quicker to say than [*giocattolino*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giocattolino) And when you say them quickly the two words can sound like one.

Comment: Your own example (coupled with my observation about English having a *lot* of words) nicely illustrates why Anglophones wouldn't adopt the superficially obvious ***toylet*** for *a small toy*. Quite apart from the fact that most toys *are* "small" (however you define that), there's the problem of homophony with ***toilet***. The other main reasons for using diminutives (affection, condescension, etc.) certainly allow [*dollies, and teddies and **toysies.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dollies%2C+and+teddies+and+toysies%22) Anglophones have all the flexibility needed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I agree that *toylet* would never work, but have you never played with "miniature soldiers"? Or those "matchbox cars" as a youngster? They look pretty small-sized to me.

Comment: My natural understanding is "a toy" is something you can hold in your hand, so I can't see why I'd need to additionally and explicitly identify a *toy soldier* or a *dinkie car* as "small". Also note that the exact context (and *referent*) massively affect how we choose to create new usages. Edgar Rice Burroughs came up with *godling*, which I like better than *godlet* because of *lordling, princeling*, for example. We have many more such suffixes than most languages ***if*** we want to use them. I quite like [postpositive adjectival **lite**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lite#Adjective)

Comment: Well, one day these comments might get deleted... and this little discussion of ours (discussionie? discussionette? hmm...) will be lost forever.

Comment: You're certainly a hard one to please! "Indirect compliment"? I thought my comment was positively gushing praise! :)

Comment: Seriously, I agree there might be elements in these comments that should be "immortalized" in an answer. But surely it would be better for *you* to identify them and add them into your answer text. To paraphrase [Arlo Guthrie,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Restaurant_(film)) one big good answer is better than two little ones.

Comment: I'm afraid of messing up the answer, and making it look *confusionario*. I'll have to think about it. (...) Just post an answer, no one is going to criticize, or, god forbid, downvote your post. Two answers is better than one. Give the folks out there something to chew on. The first sentence says: *I had better start rolling the ball...* that was the whole point of me posting an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers which reminds me, there's *itsy-bitsy*, *incy-wincy*,  *teeny-tiny*, *teeny* and *wee*...they're all used e.g. *a teeny tot*

Comment: You know English pretty well, so I bet if you think it through for long you'll be able to "authoritatively" agree with my proposition that English has many more *different* ways than Italian does for making small modifications to the form of an utterance. We've usually got more adjectives/adverbs available for any given context, *and* we can coin new usages such as [jobette](http://therelationshipdeal.com/2014/02/27/do-stay-at-home-dads-have-a-jobette/) whenever that seems like the best way to convey what you mean with exactly the right "nuance".

Comment: Last comment. You know, I thought Josh was taking it too personally, interpreting the list of comments in a too negative light,  but he was right. You *are* defending "English" against the assertion that it lacks diminutive suffixes that other European languages may or may not have. You don't have to defend it, you know. It will survive! But Italian, which is a lovely language, has its merits too. But it can never compete with English.

Comment: Last comment from me too. I didn't *feel* like I needed to "defend" English on this front (as you say, it can look after itself very well without my help). So *mea culpa* if my comments give that impression (or should that have been *pardonnez-moi* or *my bad?* :) But I probably am influenced by recent complaints on ELL that English is unnecessarily confusing because it often has several words that to a nns all seem to correspond to the same single word in *their* native language. (As you probly know, I consider true "synonyms" in English to be somewhere between "rare" and "non-existent").

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone mentioned an important factor to usage of diminutives. Although they in fact can be diminishing, diminutive forms can also express concern or thoughtfulness, especially in such cases like a parent towards their child, a person towards their pet, etc. Diminutive forms have a certain ring to them, they simply sound better. ie. someone mentioned "kitten" earlier on, imo sounding much better than a "little cat".

To be frank, in my native language (Polish) there are more than just one way to form a dimunitive from one word, making it possible to graduate a level of "diminutivity" - I'll give you "cat" example:
kot (regular cat) - kotek (little kat) - koteczek (even smaller baby cat) - kociaczek (baby cat with a certain level of tenderness) - kociątko (even smaller version and even more caressing one). Those were just 4, believe me, that more do exist.

Rules of my language actually allow me to create new, non-existing words, adding further layers of tenderness, which, even though might never exist or have existed, or sound somewhat stupid, will be fully understood by any Polish native.
As a non-native speaker please excuse me any mistakes I might have made ;-)

Comment: Konrad, you didn't read Mari-Lou's answer closely enough: it **expressly covers** the use of *little* as a substitute for the affective suffixes found in other languages. And like your native language, there are further levels of diminutive in English too: it's just that instead of using different suffixes, we use compound adjectival forms like *tiny little*, [*itty-bitty*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itty-bitty) and [*teeny-weeny*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teeny-weeny), which can also incorporate an affective signal.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica : The difference is that while "itty-bitty, teeny-weeny piglet" is still comprised of known words or phrases, Polish's use of suffixes makes it possible to build a whole new word that is quite easily understood due to a recognizable base and a boatload of suffix-like modifications piled on it. I can turn "pies" into "piesunieczek" or "psiapsiuńcio" which veer on childlike gobbledygook, while remaining perfectly understandable.

Answer (score -2):

> Why are diminutives in English not always formed by adding a suffix, like in French for instance?

To add to the [excellent answer by Mari-Lou](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/296763/167396), there is another reason why diminutives aren't regularly formed by adding a suffix: in English we can also readily create a diminutive form of a noun by adding the [combining form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combining%20form) *mini-*.

### [**mini-**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mini-)

> combining form
>
> **Definition of *mini-* (Entry 3 of 3)**
>   : smaller or briefer than usual, normal, or standard
>   - *mini*course
>   - *mini*bus
>
> [from Merriam-Webster]

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mini-#etymonline_v_44831) gives the following etymology:

> word-forming element meaning "miniature, minor," abstracted from **miniature**, with sense perhaps influenced by **minimum**. The vogue for *mini-* as a prefix in English word coinage dates from c. 1960; *minicam* for "miniature camera" (1937) is an early use.

I suspect that the combining form *mini-* is preferable to the suffix *-let* in forming diminutives of nouns because it flags the semantic variation *in advance* rather than as an afternote, and the first syllable must be *stressed* (therefore giving the diminutive a degree of emphasis) compared to the usually unstressed suffix (e.g. in *booklet, platelet, starlet*, etc). It's certainly the case that using *mini-* to create a diminutive will be more readily understood than using the suffix *let*, even if it's unfamiliar - say, *mini-answer* rather than *answerlet*. In fact, many such diminutives have become sufficiently familiar for the hyphen to have disappeared:

- [*minibar*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/minibar) rather than *barlet*
- [*minicar*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minicar) rather than [*carlet*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carlet) (which is a file used by combmakers)
- [*minibus*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minibus) rather than *buslet*
- [*miniskirt*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miniskirt) rather than *skirtlet*
- [*miniseries*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miniseries) rather than *serieslet*; etc.