# Do false diminutives exist in English?

Tags: derivational-morphology, diminutives

In some languages, there are *false diminutives*, by which I mean words which have diminutive suffixes but don't express either small size or affectionately emotive meanings.

For example, in Italian, *-ina* is a feminine diminutive suffix; for example, *strada* is a road, and a *stradina* is a narrow road. But *cantina* (*cellar*) is not a diminutive of *canto* (*song*). Similarly, in Dutch, *tussendoortje* (*snack*) is not a diminutive of *tussendoor* (*in between*), though it has the *-je* diminutive ending. And in German, there is the *[Verselbständigte Diminutive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/)*, so the *-chen* is not (or no longer) diminutive in words like *drachen* (*dragon*) or *mätz­chen* (*foolish antics*).

Does English have false diminutives as well?

Comment: You should give some examples.

Comment: You will find this question and its answer interesting, [Diminutive forms in English.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296694/diminutive-forms-in-english).

Comment: The question [How are diminutives formed in recent English words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/how-are-diminutives-formed-in-recent-english-words) convenientlly lists suffixes often marking diminutives (in either sense: a small version of the referent, or a pet name for the referent). But I don't think the term 'false diminutive' is standard in analysis, as English affixes are well known to code for multiple senses.

Comment: Are there any diminutives in English that are used as diminutives universally enough that a non-dimunitive use of them is worthy of being called *false*? The most common diminutive ending in English may be *-y* or *_ie* — *doggie, kitty, piggy, laddie, lassie, missy, hanky* — but there are so many non-dimunitives ending in *-y* and *-ie* that you can hardly call them false.

Comment: @PeterShor: perhaps the best way to distinguish is by if it is historically a diminutive suffix, although this requires some etymological research and the answer may not always be clear.

Comment: Let's not forget "My Little Chickadee", applied by W C Fields to Mae West, who was definitely not diminutive.

Answer (score 8):

There are some suffixes which can be used in more than one way and might be considered false diminutives. I admit I'm still not 100% clear on what you mean by this term. Here are a couple of examples.

-ette (or -et) is often used as a diminutive suffix (kitchenette, cigarette) but could denote a feminine form (suffragette or majorette) or something that is an imitation (leatherette).

-ling is a Middle English suffix that has survived in a few forms such as youngling or duckling. It can also denote association as in hireling or appear as a sort of orthographical coincidence as in "pie filling".

Hope this helps.

Comment: A fine answer to a question that needs adjusting. The terminology is probably inappropriate for English; is 'kitchenette' not a false 'femininitive' or 'imitative'?

Comment: @AndyT You need to learn to distinguish between the normal usage and the 'word-as-a-word' usage of a word. Here, the quotes around _kitchenette_ indicate the word-as-a-word usage. (Those round _femininitive_ and _imitative_ indicate non-standard terms.)

Answer (score 1):

A.I .Makarova was the first to use the term "false diminutives " in her bookМакарова А. И. Именная диминутивная система молдавского языка. (Дери- вация): дис. ... канд. филол. наук. Кишинев, 1970. According to her classification example kitchenette is a diminutive It is equal to a small kitchen but satinette,muslinette ,letherette are false diminutives Do you know any other false diminutives?